# Updating Java Keystore and Truststores with new Certificates

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2

We have a remote java client application that uses two-way TLSv1.2 verification.
Meaning the server authenticates with the client and then the client authenticates with the server.

This is achieved using .jks files which contain signed certificates from a certificate signing authority and using an SSLSocketFactory.

Is is possible to add new certificates (from the same authority) within the same keystores and truststores alongside the current certificates?

Will Java "fail-over" to the new certificates after the current certificates expire?

If so, this would allow us to roll-out new key/truststores in batches, rather than having to replace all the certificates on both the server-side and client-side in a single enterprise-wide deployment.

For example, we could update the server side with new stores containing both the current and new certificate chains.  Then we could spread-out deployment of stores to the client-side containing the new certificate chains over several days.

Some clients handshaking with the current chain and some clients handshaking with the new chain.

Is the SSL implementation smart enough to try all the chains available in the stores and/or, on the day the current certificate chains expire, will Java just "fail-over" to using the new certificate chains?

We could then remove the expired chains from the store the next time we need to update the stores with new chains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do what you want but it requires you or whoever maintains your Java client to program it. The keystore that stores your keys can obviously contain as many keypairs you would want it to contain. When a TLS is negotiated between the server and your client, the server can send a list of DN of certificate authorities it can accept. Then your client decides which one to pick from your keystore. The default Java implementation goes through the list of DNs sent by the server and checks if they match the Issuer DN on the certificates in the client keystore. When a certificate that matches is found it is selected to be sent to the server for authentication. If two certificates match, then a preference is given to the one that is not expired. See [JDK-8132108](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8132108) for more details. Now, this is the default behavior. If you want more control, you need to implement your own X509KeyManager and implement whatever logic you want for client certificate selection.

Comment: It sounds like the default behavior meets my requirements.

Comment: BTW, how did you find the issue report?

Comment: I tend to monitor these kind of issues in Oracle's bug tracking system. My job is in infosec.